# Sending email in R version 3.6.0 via outlook by RDCOMClient package

Tags: r, rdcomclient

I updated R in version 3.6.0. Then I started to have problem with Library RDCOMClient. Does anyone know how to solve problem with R version 3.6.0 and library RDCOMClient? Or does it exist some alternative way how to send emails in R via Outlook?

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> Warning in install.packages :   package ‘RDCOMClient’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with the [mailR](https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR) package in the past. Might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem, try installing it this way :

```
install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")
```

Tell me if it worked for you.

Comment: It worked for R version 3.5., but not for version 3.6.

Comment: What about this way : ``devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient")``

Comment: Also is RDCOMClient the only package giving you an error?

Comment: No, it didnt work. But I manually downloaded package from this site http://www.omegahat.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/ (file PACKAGES.gz from folder for R version 3.5.) and it works.